# Android : Application crashes after its configured using progurad

Tags: android, proguard

I just developed my application and want to release but before that i want to remove the logs and other unnecessary things. The best way i find that to use [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). I am using command line so i use the command `ant release` and my application is built successfully and the new apk file which is generated in /bin directory is `<app-name>-release.apk`. I installed that apk in my device but after few screens its crashed and when i tried with restating my application and moved to other tabs then its crashed at some points.

Don't know why its happened. so this is the contain of my `project.properties` file
`target=android-15`
`proguard.config=proguard-project.txt`

And this is my `proguard-project.txt`

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-libraryjars smack.jar
-libraryjars libphonenumber-5.0v1.5.jar
#-keep class com.** { *; }
#-keep class org.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
10-08 07:25:18.356: E/AndroidRuntime(1733): FATAL EXCEPTION: Contact_sync_Service
10-08 07:25:18.356: E/AndroidRuntime(1733): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil
10-08 07:25:18.356: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at org.sipchat.sipua.ui.ai.run(Unknown 
Source)
10-08 07:25:18.356: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-08 07:26:26.756: E/dalvikvm(1751): Could not find class 'org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter', referenced from method org.sipchat.sipua.ui.ConnectionService.a
10-08 07:26:26.786: E/dalvikvm(1751): Could not find class 'org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration', referenced from method org.sipchat.sipua.ui.ConnectionService.onStartCommand
10-08 07:26:26.806: E/dalvikvm(1751): Could not find class 'org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration', referenced from method org.sipchat.sipua.ui.af.run
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at org.sipchat.sipua.ui.ConnectionService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-08 07:26:26.956: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update :**

The packages which are mentioned in error are the packages of jar files which i added already in `proguard-project.txt`

Please make me clear if i went wrong anywhere?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the crash details from logcat?  "Crashes" can be caused by lots of different things.

Comment: i used to send the `<app-name>-release.apk` file in mail and from there i am installing it in my device in this case my logcat doesn't show any output. while running in emulator the `<app-name>.apk` file gets installed and with that its not crashing

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been clear: Without a description of what's going wrong, no-one's going to be able to tell you how to fix it.  "Crashing" can mean a lot of things.  If it's an unhandled exception, we need to know what that exception is.  If it's something else, we need to know what you mean by "Crashing".

Comment: The apk `<app-name>-release.apk` i just renamed it with `<app-name>.apk` after deleting the orginal apk . but this apk runs fine there is no crash why? and about exception how do i handle the exception in proguard?

Comment: I'm not going to be able to provide much more help here unless you can describe the crash.  Sorry.

Comment: okay i am trying to get the crash once i have i will post it

Comment: i just added the logcat please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Did you gave Dexguard a try? As it says on the proguard website

> ProGuard now has a sibling optimizer and obfuscator for Android:
>   DexGuard. It is compatible with ProGuard, and it provides additional
>   features like string encryption, class encryption, and hiding access
>   to sensitive APIs. It directly targets Dalvik bytecode and streamlines
>   the Android build process.

http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to know what is the problem with my current code of `proguard-project.txt` file. if i made the mistake in progurd configuration then i must fix it first then i should try with dexguard

Comment: sure - just threw it in for the case you overlooked it or for the other people stumbling over this question - good luck getting your concrete answer